# Malformed Request Line With SSL on Ubuntu

Tags: ssl, devops, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I'm in the process of setting up a droplet at DigitalOcean. I would like to serve multiple sites from the same droplet and use LetsEncrypt SSL certs. When accessing a test site, I see an error in the logs *"AH00566: request failed: malformed request line"* and in the Chrome I see "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

It seems that I likely have a configuration error somewhere but am not sure where.

The conf for my site is:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      ServerName mydomain.com
      ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
      RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com [OR]
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:443>
    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com>
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
   </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you run `curl -I mydomain.com` and to share the results?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 14:34:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: the most interesting part is a location. I see you've replaced it with example.com. Does the original answer include https as protocol and 80 as port?

Comment: yes the only thing I changed was the output domain for the sake of stack overflow. Not ready to reveal the domain just yet :)

Comment: it's not clear which server logs the error. But it is either you're  trying to access port 80 with https or port 443 with http try to run `curl -IL mydomain.com` it will follow the redirect and if there is an issue you will see it

Comment: It returns this error: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Comment: It’s kind of hard to understand in that way. Could you update the question with full output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204078/discussion-between-plumwd-and-yuri-g).